# JSP Hibernate zero to one

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to achive connection like on this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFRsJ.jpg), where I used MySQL. I read about @OneToOne but it looks like both of Classes would contain FK.

In this example I would like to have Department FK in Employee, but don't have Employee FK in Department. (Employee can be in department, but it is not obligatory - can be null).

I am not sure if it is even a thing or if it's along convention.

**DepartmentEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class DepartmentEntity implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;

    public DepartmentEntity() {
    }

    public DepartmentEntity(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String lastname;
    @Column(length = 11)
    private String pesel;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date birthdate;

    @Column
    private Integer department;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    private boolean active;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `@ZeroToOne` tag. You have to use a  `@OneToOne` relationship. That tag does not imply that two foreign key are going to be created. Use `@OneToOne` in conjuction with ' `@JoinColumn` in the EmployeeEntity pointing to the a DepartmentEntity not to an Integer.

Comment: But in that case wouldn't I have Department FK in Employee?

Comment: Yes but I think that you can model the relation to be nullable using the attribute `optional=true` in the @OneToOne tag.